# Find out if there are selected more than one on Checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

That is how I have a checkbox and it must be such that when for example, I click on my button, so it must be like to know that there must be more than one of them. So it must have more value in total.

As it is right now gives no error or success message in my console.log ().

```
<input type="checkbox"
        ng-checked="ItemSelected"
        name="SelectedTypes"
        value="2" />
<input type="checkbox"
        ng-checked="ItemSelected"
        name="SelectedTypes"
        value="3" />
<input type="checkbox"
        ng-checked="ItemSelected"
        name="SelectedTypes"
        value="4" />

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Næste" ng-click="UppersViewClick()" />
```

**CreateUserInfo.js - File**

```
$scope.UppersViewClick = function ()
{
    if ($scope.ItemSelected !== undefined)
    {
        if ($scope.ItemSelected.length > 1) {
            $scope.UppersViewInfo = false;
            $scope.PantsViewInfo = true;
            console.log("succes")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }
}
```

So the purpose it is that I should be sure me that more than one or just a value out of it all.

Comment: Do u want to check all checkboxes on button click? Or what exactly is your purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get checked boxes like that since all refers to the same model,

```
 $scope.records = [ { "Id": 1 }, { "Id": 2 }, { "Id": 3 } ];
```

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [ { "Id": 1 }, { "Id": 2 }, { "Id": 3 } ];
    $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.ShowSelected = function() {
      $scope.records = $.grep($scope.records, function( record ) {
        return $scope.selected[ record.Id ];
      });
    };      
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="record in records">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[record.Id]"> {{record.Id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="ShowSelected()">Show Selected</a>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```